# Problem with preloading the association in elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a bank and branch schema. So the bank has many branches but when I create a bank it should fetch the branch id and its details.

bank schema

```
defmodule Banking.Schema.Bank do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  alias Banking.Schema.Branch

  schema "banks" do
    field :name, :string
    has_many :branches, Branch

    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(bank, attrs) do
    bank
    |> cast(attrs, [:name])
    |> validate_required([:name])
    |> Repo.preload(:branches)
  end
end
```

branch schema

```
defmodule Banking.Schema.Branch do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  alias Banking.Model.Bank, as: BankModel
  alias Banking.Schema.Bank

  @primary_key {:ifsc, :string, []}

  schema "branches" do
    field :branch, :string
    field :address, :string
    field :city, :string
    field :district, :string
    field :state, :string
    belongs_to :bank, Bank

    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(branch, attrs) do
   branch
    |> cast(attrs, [:ifsc, :branch, :address, :city, :district, :state])
    |> validate_required([:ifsc, :branch, :address, :city, :district, :state])
    |> put_assoc(:bank, attrs["bank"])
  end
end
```

As you can see for the branch schema I have created a primary key for ifsc code.

So what I want is when I create a changeset for the bank. I want the branch detail by there ifsc code.

```
bank = Bank.changeset(%Bank{}, %{name: "sbi", branch: "122"})
```

Like this but right now I'm not able to preload the branch.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot preload a `changeset`, they are used to verify whether the constraints are correct and this happens before a record is fetched/inserted. If you take a look at the documentation of [Repo.preload](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:preload/3):

> Preloads all associations on the given struct or structs.
>
> This is similar to Ecto.Query.preload/3 except it allows you to
>   preload structs **after they have been fetched from the database**.

What you need to do in your code is first get/insert the changeset into the database and then preload the result struct (remove Repo.preload from changeset):

```
Bank.changeset(%Bank{}, %{name: "sbi"})
|> Repo.insert() # here you get the struct of the inserted record
|> Repo.preload(:branches)
```